# Calculation time for a limit, is my calculation still calculating?

Tags: evaluation, kernel, timing, system-limitations

I am calculating the limit of an eighth order derivative with ~700 terms. The notebook has been in the 'running' phase for a few days now. If it says it is still running, does this necessarily mean that it is? Should I expect a result?

Comment: If it says it's running, it must be running. You can always look at the CPU usage of the Mathematica kernel process.  How long will it take?  It's impossible to tell. You just need to decide on how long you're willing to wait.  (Well, you could evaluate limits of increasingly longer expressions, time them, and extrapolate from there.)

Comment: @Szabolcs Probably not the issue here, but are you considering formatting to count as running?

Comment: @ming.vase Can you break up the calculation into pieces?  I.e., calculate (and store) the limit of one or a few terms at a time.  Then the progress of the calculation should be more apparent.  This should work as long as the limits of the individual terms converge.

Comment: @jjc385 that is a good idea. I will consider it. I don't know to what extent formatting is being considered, I am just using the basic Limit[] function.

Comment: @Szabolcs thats a good point. I didn't know if a sort of 'hanging calculation' phenomena could occur, somehow causing CPU usage for an impossible task.